# Aliasing the sharepoint server name? http://<servername>

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, alternate-access-mapping, dns

We have SharePoint being installed on a new VM server and our servername is SEVERELY obtuse. How can I add a 'friendly' name and have it map to the server?

e.g.

```
current servename is "hbswethelsl100"

`I cannot imagine having our server be     
http://hbswethelsl100/sites/mysite

I want it to be http://myfriendlyname
or even http://myfriendlyname/sites/mysite
```

When I brought this up to our network admin they had difficulty figuring out how to do this, is it possible?  What are the steps?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a binding to the iis and modify the alternate access mapping in the ca for the webapplication.

hope that helps?

Comment: Are you really hoping that helps, without giving at least a few steps on how to accomplish the things you mention ;)

Comment: I Hope :) behause i am at the iPad there is it to Hard to search a small example and so on :(

Comment: Okay, so here is a guide for 2010: http://practicalsharepoint.blogspot.se/2011/02/sharepoint-2010-alternate-access.html?m=1 and for 2013 with a nice intro to AAM: http://blog.blksthl.com/2012/12/03/a-guide-to-alternate-access-mappings-basics-in-sharepoint-2013/

Comment: Thx for helping me out